# Can I use my python custom objects in VBA?

Tags: python, excel, vba, com

It's clear that there are options to use **python functions** in excel/VBA.(xlwings, Pyxll, DataNitro).

However, I'm looking for ways to use **my python objects** in VBA. In my ideal world, I would be just able to do something like this:

```
dim car1 as object
dim car2 as object
dim road as object

set road = CreateObject("MyPythonLib.road")
set car1 = CreateObject("MyPythonLib.car")
set car2 = CreateObject("MyPythonLib.car")

road.add(car1)
road.add(car2)
```

Comment: Have you searched for ways of making a COM  DLL component in Python?  Or a server application?  And setting up InProcServer32 or LocalServer32, CLSID, ProgId, etc? And possibly making a type library so you can inspect your Python objects in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

The last time I checked, Excel VBA is restricted to a limited set of the .NET Framework. That said, you can still make calls to C# if you want to translate the Python to C#.